# Running a series of scripts in MySQL

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I have files named like:

```
File1_01.sql
File1_02.sql
File2_01.sql
File2_02.sql
```

I need to run all the scripts for File1 first (but these can be done in parallel), then all the scripts for File2.  What's my best way to do this?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Do you need this in a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about "best" way, but I would probably not do it in parallel, just something simple like:

```
for sql in *.sql; do
   mysql options <"$sql"
done
```

If you *need* to do it in parallel:

```
for prefix in File1 File2; do
  for sql in ${prefix}_*.sql; do
    mysql options <"$sql" &
  done
  wait
done
```

This will first take the `File1*` files and start MySQL in parallel. Then wait for them to end before doing the same with all the `File2*` files.

Comment: The second one looks great, but it seems it doesn't interpret the wildcard?

    ./load_files.sh: line 5: File2_*.sql: No such file or directory

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot.  It works great, thanks.